# Conflicting peer dependency when installing NGRX

Tags: angular, npm, ionic-framework, ngrx, ngrx-store

When trying to install NGRX from NPM for my ionic project with angular, I get a error.

I use this command

```
npm install @ngrx/store --save
```

but i end up with this error:

While resolving: @ngrx/eslint-plugin@14.0.2
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @angular-eslint/builder@13.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/builder@"~13.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin@13.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin@"~13.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   13 more (@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">=8.0.0" from @ngrx/eslint-plugin@14.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngrx/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @ngrx/eslint-plugin@"^14.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.21.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=8.0.0" from @ngrx/eslint-plugin@14.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ngrx/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @ngrx/eslint-plugin@"^14.0.2" from the root project

I have no idea of how to resolve this, any help would be greatful!

Comment: Help us to help you by sharing your package.json

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the @ngrx/eslint-plugin and installing an older version of it which doesn't have these dependency conflicts.

Be aware that the older version is marked as deprecated.

```
npm r eslint-plugin-ngrx

npm i eslint-plugin-ngrx@1.47.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on the latest version of Ionic, adding NGRX with Angular CLI: `ng add @ngrx/store`.

I was able to resolve the issue by installing @ngrx with NPM: `npm install @ngrx/store` rather than using Angular CLI.